# How to start at x = 0 with given xrange in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

in gnuplot, is it possible to start the graph at x = 0 in given x range?

Let say that I have this code:

```
set xrange [100:500]
plot "input.txt" using 2:1:(1.0) notitle with lines lw 1
```

Consequently, the graph will start at x = 100 and end at x = 500. 
I want the graph to start at x = 0 and end at x = 400 with the given range [100:500].
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused with your question. If you want the graph to start at x=0 and end at x=400, just set the xrange to [0:400].

Comment: I want to make the x=100 value in my data as x=0 value in my graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an xrange of `[0:400]` and subtract 100 from your data values:

```
set xrange [0:400]
plot "input.txt" using ($2-100):1 with lines
```